# Append object[,] data in Excel using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus-4

How can I append `object[, ]` data in Excel using **EPPlus**?
I'm using the following code but it returns `System.Object` as the result in  Excel.

```
object[,] rowdate = new object[dt.Rows.Count, Nodes.Split(',').Length * 2 + 4];
ExcelRange _excelRange = _excelSheet.Cells[excelRange];
 _excelRange.Value = rowdate;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Jansi. To help others help you, you need to provide little more details and show a verifiable code. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Setting the value of a range probably applies that value to all cells in that range. Looks like you'll just have to use a loop.

Comment: Hi, I'm adding the values into rowdate by looping and i needs to append the entire rowdate[, ] object into excel with the desired range. can any else option used than loop?

Comment: Yes. I have achieved this with looping. Thanks for your comments